# Internal Storage and Files?

Tags: android, file

I'm trying to create a file in the internal storage

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when i search in /data/data/ i don't find the app dir to see the file presence...why? I try with a context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir() but it don't work it give error. How can i do? What is/are my mistake(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
File path = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(path, filename);
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
outputStream.close();
```

you should probably do a google search before posting.

The file will be located in

data->data->package name->files->filename

Comment: i searched and i didn't found nothing....so i ask here....i'm sorry if i'm not expert but i have just started to learn....

so i try to use this and it not give the error...but when can i see the path? I insert the code in a button, at te onCreate of the main activity...

Comment: @MattiaRomagnoli you can use ddms to browser through your emulator.

Comment: in /data/data/...there isn't the package of my app...it is the fist thing that i searched

Comment: @MattiaRomagnoli are you using an emulator? unless you root the device, you can't view the app contents

Comment: no i'm using my phone and i use the ES Tool to search and i can see all the package but not mine @Hades

Comment: @MattiaRomagnoli What's your use case?

Comment: i want to create an app to save, open and use file and image in/from the internal storage @Hades

Comment: it a test for a n other project but it the first time that i use files in android @Hades

Comment: @MattiaRomagnoli http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html read that

Comment: `i'm using my phone and i use the ES Tool to search and i can see all the package `. Nonsense. ES File Explorer has no access to /data or /data/data.  Where you are looking at is something like /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/data......

Comment: @freenapps i havn't nothing in that dir..
only in /data/data/...i have the packages of all my apps but not the mine

Comment: I said `something like`. That path could also begin with /sdcard or /storage . Look for /Android/ in it. So your phone is rooted? You were asked that before.

Answer (score 0):

File Explorers have no access to the /data directory.

With getFilesDir() you will know the directory where you put your file.

Comment: How an i use it? I try with Context.getFilesDir() but it give error

Comment: I dont know what error you got. Thats because you did not tell. Did you google for example code?

Comment: i declared 
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        context.getFilesDir();

Comment: You are not giving the info asked for. Nor do you try to give more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
outputStream = context.getFilesDir().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

getFilesDir() returns the Absolute path to the file .

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir())